# how to detect and remove duplicate data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                eui   BatV  TempC_DS  TempC_SHT  \
0     A8404181D1822E6B  2.985     16.25      16.03   
1     A84041A3A1822FE5  2.982      7.06      16.28   
2     A8404181D1822E6B  2.985     16.31      16.09   
3     A84041A3A1822FE5  2.982      7.93      16.43   
4     A8404181D1822E6B  2.983     16.50      16.20   
...                ...    ...       ...        ...   
2565  A8404181D1822E6B  3.007     21.75      22.04   
2566  A84041A3A1822FE5  3.005     13.68      19.42   
2567  A8404181D1822E6B  3.007     21.81      22.10   
2568  A84041A3A1822FE5  3.001     14.00      19.62   
2569  A8404181D1822E6B  3.007     21.87      22.14   

              EventEnqueuedUtcTime                                    id  \
0     2021-02-02T08:05:47.1660000Z  5f185a0d-5000-4831-889c-a48c431ca894   
1     2021-02-02T08:21:57.9240000Z  41c21f2f-0160-464c-901c-24c0a1119dc0   
2     2021-02-02T08:25:47.8710000Z  9781d546-56ab-4ccb-b7dd-de4415a949c4   
3     2021-02-02T08:41:57.4140000Z  de3e9ea0-3752-4cef-9056-554b66c83447   
4     2021-02-02T08:45:47.8500000Z  a3436591-eb8e-4705-9aeb-a43684d560f3   
...                            ...                                   ...   
2565  2021-02-24T08:05:55.6210000Z  3695d621-d69a-4ed2-8b52-0e90c9464a05   
2566  2021-02-24T08:22:28.3730000Z  f3fd3356-e88c-43ce-af96-f7fd0141d0d4   
2567  2021-02-24T08:25:55.6160000Z  a85dae5d-dc94-4618-b95e-9c3c04668821   
2568  2021-02-24T08:42:24.9720000Z  148d6118-4c35-4337-9508-78818d1886f6   
2569  2021-02-24T08:45:55.7560000Z  3730aa39-0ddd-44f2-9c88-ed0e096526b7
```

and when I try to use Azure Auto ML with timeseries, then I get this error:

```
Error: Found duplicated rows for EventEnqueuedUtcTime and ['eui'] combinations. Please make sure the time series identifier setting is correct so that each series represents one time-series, or clean the data to make sure there are no duplicates before passing to AutoML.
```

How can I remove with pandas, the duplicated rows  combination of(eui,EventEnqueuedUtcTime                                    )

Comment: You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Why do you want to drop duplicates using pandas and not spark if in Azure? `df.dropDuplicates().show()` Spark, `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['eui','EventEnqueuedUtcTime'], inplace=True)#df.drop_duplicates(subset=['eui'], inplace=True)` pandas

Comment: Spark?..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use DataFrame.drop_duplicates (subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False).

Try to read this guide.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: how can I see the duplicates before removing them?